# How to pull params from a form_for for into a string without setting to Object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I am trying to pull all of the values of `<input>` fields in a `form_for` and populate a string with them. I would not like to do `form_for` `@instance_variable` as I would not like to submit the params as the initialization of an Object.

In case you are wondering why I want to do this seemingly backwards thing, I am trying to have a form within a view, grab all the input values, put it into a string, and that use that string for the body of an email that would be delivered via a `Mailer`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recomendation would be something like this:

```
<%= form_tag foobar_path do %>
  <p>
    <%= label_tag :email %><br />
    <%= text_field_tag :email, params[:email] %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= label_tag :another_field %><br />
    <%= text_field_tag :another_field, params[:another_field] %>
  </p>
  <%= submit_tag "Submit"%>
<% end %>
```

Then in your controller do something like this:

```
def foobar
    Mailer.send_something(params[:email],params[:another_field]).deliver
end
```

Is there a reason why this will not work and you really need to make an instance of an object?

Comment: Well I tried doing `form_for @variable` but I hadn't initialized it to anything So I was getting unexpected keyword `end` error in the controller method that was connected to the view. So then I thought that it would make more sense to just grab the params directly if possible as opposed to sending it to an object. Thank you sir!